# How to map arrows with free group functor from Set to Grp

Tags: category-theory, functors

I am having a bit of trouble understanding the free functor, T: **Set** $\rightarrow$ **Grp**, where T($A$) = Free group generated by $A$. The question I have  in mind is how do I map arrows. In **Set**, the arrows are just functions from $A$ to $B$, with no regards to any structure whatsoever. But in **Grp**, the arrows are group morphisms. I cant figure out how to map my arrows in **Set** to a morphism between groups.

Any hints or insight is deeply appreciated

Cheers